# Confused by kmeans results

Tags: python, clustering, k-means

I am using kmeans to cluster some data with 2 features. Not sure I understand why kmeans is producing the clusters I see:

[image: kmeans results]

Why would kmeans not cluster these points in a way that matches what we would expect visually looking at the data? Why are seemingly random points in the middle of visual clusters being put into a second cluster like that?

The code I am running:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
features = map(lambda x: df[x], cols)
input = np.matrix(list(zip(*features)))

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(input)
input_scaled = scaler.transform(input)

algo = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
algo.fit(input_scaled)
df['cluster'] = pd.Series(algo.labels_)

sns.lmplot(x=cols[0],y=cols[1],data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='cluster')
```

Comment: For one, your features are on such different scales that the x dimension completely dominates. I suspect it's a problem in how you're determining and plotting the cluster assignments. You should inspect the cluster centers instead

Comment: Why would you do kmeans for two features? You can eyeball it with only 2 dimensions

Comment: It would help if we could reproduce the experiment. Could you provide the list of data-points and link/reference to the KMeans code/library you are utilizing. Besides that, I'd suggest reading the documentation. Typically, kmeans implementations randomly reinitialize a cluster with random assignment(s), when all its points get assigned to another cluster, which might be the problem here. Using Mahalanobis metric instead of Euclidean would help. Initialization of cluster centers? Try multiple runs, if cluster centers disagree a lot then you have a problem.

Comment: @SeanOwen I am plotting them with their actual values, but I am using StandardScaler to create the inputs for the algorithm. Does your comment still apply?

Comment: @DarrinThomas Because once my data is labeled by this clustering step, I then plot a bunch of other graphs and display the data points using colors driven by the clustering labels. Helps me determine visually where the clusters fall when breaking the data down differently. Make sense?

Comment: @DynamicStardust From sklearn, I have tried KMeans, SpectralClustering, Birch, MeanShift, DBSCAN, AgglomerativeClustering and AffinityPropogation, and all basically return the same output.

For KMeans, multiple runs return the same cluster centers.

here is the data:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/confused-by-kmeans-results

Comment: @DynamicStardust what's even more confusing is that the centers look right when printed out:

> print(scaler.inverse_transform(acctModel.cluster_centers_))

```
[[  9292.46666667    393.16666667]
 [ 85633.            123.75      ]]
```

yet the assignment of the points to the centers seems weird. Do you get what is going on?

Comment: @ArielJakobovits You can try to debug this by using different parameter options for 'init' with random_state and 'algorithm', and 'verbose'=1, detailed here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html. You can also visualize the cluster assignments every n (say n=10) iterations. A suggestion is to assign 'init' with centroids at 'opposite ends' of the data scatter and perceive how they update with each iteration. If none of these 'work' then you can submit an issue report to sklearn devs, who can help you further.

Comment: Tried guessing the data  and reran your code. Got makes sense clusters. Can you please provide the data? Does this still occur?

Comment: @DaFanat thanks for helping, here's the data...https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/confused-by-kmeans-results

Comment: If DBSCAN and k-means return "essentially the same result" for all parameters, then you certainly are not looking at the clustering result, but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Thanks to everyone who helped. The issue had nothing to do with kmeans.

I did not realize that when you do this:

dataframe[col] = Series, the series gets merged based on the index, as opposed to a simple appending of the column.

My dataframe had been filtered before I generated the lists of features, so the index was not 0,1,2 but rather 0,2,5, etc. I needed to perform reset_index() on the original dataframe before assigning a new column in the dataframe to the labels from the algorithm.

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong in accepting your answer as marked and correct.